# installing SRILM using cygwin and get "iconv.h: No such file or directory # include_next <iconv.h>" error

Tags: compiler-errors, cygwin, package, srilm

I'm trying to install SRILM using Cygwin with the help of [this tutorial](http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/index.php?title=SRILM_Installation_and_Running_Tutorial) and I get this error:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/srilm/zlib/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/srilm'
make release-libraries
make[1]: Entering directory '/srilm'
for subdir in misc dstruct lm flm lattice utils zlib; do \
        (cd $subdir/src; make SRILM=/srilm MACHINE_TYPE=cygwin64 OPTION= MAKE_PIC= release-libraries) || exit 1; \
done
make[2]: Entering directory '/srilm/misc/src'
g++ -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-uninitialized -DINSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES    -I. -I../../include   -c -g -O2 -o ../obj/cygwin64/File.o File.cc
In file included from File.cc:25:0:
srilm_iconv.h:15:25: fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <iconv.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
/srilm/common/Makefile.common.targets:93: recipe for target '../obj/cygwin64/File.o' failed
make[2]: *** [../obj/cygwin64/File.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/srilm/misc/src'
Makefile:109: recipe for target 'release-libraries' failed
make[1]: *** [release-libraries] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/srilm'
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'World' failed
make: *** [World] Error 2
```

I checked iconv package several times during cygwin re-installation.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

P.S. I am using Windows 8.1,  srilm-1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following several lines into "c:\cygwin\home\yourname.bashrc" file:

```
export SRILM=/srilm
export MACHINE_TYPE=cygwin
export PATH=$PATH:$pwd:$SRILM/bin/cygwin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$SRILM/man
```

and everything is fine.